# Is there a faster way to mirror Android Devices using python?

Tags: python, subprocess, adb

I am designing an application that mirrors my Android Devices to my desktop using adb. But apparently this method only takes 1 screenshot every 2 seconds.

```py
import subprocess
import cv2, os
while True:
    subprocess.run(["adb", "shell", "screencap ","/sdcard/screen.png"], shell=True)
    subprocess.run(["adb", "pull", "/sdcard/screen.png"], shell=True)
    print("Capped")
    image = cv2.imread("screen.png")
    os.remove("screen.png") #in order to make sure that the image isnt overwrited the next iteration
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
       sys.exit()
```

Is there any other way through which i can mirror my screen faster?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **Screen Copy (scrcpy tool)**, which mirrors your Android phone on your machine.